# Sencha Touch Carousel randomisation

Tags: random, sencha-touch, carousel

I currently have  a static carousel set up as below:

```
  varPanelTop = new Ext.Carousel({
        defaults: {
            cls: 'homeTop'
        },
        items: [{
            html: '<img src="IMAGE ONE" />'
        },
        {
            html: '<img src="IMAGE TWO" />'
        },
        {
            html: '<img src="IMAGE THREE" />'
        },
        {
            html: '<img src="IMAGE FOUR" />'
}]
  });
```

Not a problem all works fine, but now i have been thrown a big one, in which 'can i do this  so that each time this page is refreshed the order of the html/imgs are different each time?

So would this be possible to do and how if so?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Have an array with objects like this:

```
var images = [{html:'<img src="i1.jpg" />'},{html:'<img src="i2.jpg" />'},{html:'<img src="i3.jpg" />'},{html:'<img src="i4.jpg" />'}];
```

Then depending when you show the carousel you will have:

```
Ext.getCmp('carouselId').items.add(images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]);
```

etc. you can check if the images were added already i.e. all you need is a list of random numbers and you add the images to the carousel like that. Afterwards you call

```
Ext.getCmp('carouselId').doLayout();
```

to display the images.

Note that carouselId is the "id" property of the carousel object, but there are better ways to get to the carousel object. It all depends where you have it.

Comment: Of course, don't have the items in the carousel config object.

Comment: thanks for the replies will get back once I have looked at this thanks